# RecyclerView items not displaying as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Hello and sorry for not adding the images on this page, I don't have enough reputation yet

[This is how it's supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYHO0.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNj0h.png) is how it's displaying in the recyclerView, as you can see I want to have the image on the left with the centered text on the right, how can I achieve this?

Here's the code for the item layout

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRowCompany"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/library_icon"

        android:visibility="visible"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/Blue"
        app:civ_border_width="2.5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRowCompanyName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text="CompanyName"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgRowCompany"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The recyclerAdapter code:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override//Number od items to be returned
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       CircleImageView imageRowCompany;
       TextView companyName;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageRowCompany=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgRowCompany);
            companyName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRowCompanyName);
        }
    }
}
```

And the recyclerView code :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CompanyLibrary"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you've posted is on RTL device. End to end and start to start is working expected manner, if you want to show in the your manner then use

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" instead of 
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

and

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" instead of 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```